# Excel Custom Function not supporting in Other Office versions

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created an excel custom function in **SharedRuntime**. I have used **JavaScript 1.1 version** and **SharedRuntime 1.1 version**. My custom function is working fine in **office 365**, but it's not working in offices **2013**, **2016**, and **2019**.
I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone tell me where I am doing a mistake.

Comment: It makes sense to list the precise Office versions where the add-in doesn't work correctly. Is it a volume-licensed version?

Answer (score 4):

The *shared runtime* may not be supported on *older* Office versions. You can check out the minimum Office versions in the [Shared runtime requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/shared-runtime-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview) section.